# Memory error in combination with pandas, bokeh and python 2.7

Tags: python, memory, pandas, bokeh

I have a csv-file that is about 100 mb small. Then I have plenty of memory, about 8 Gb. At runtime I don't have more than, at conservative guess, say 10 `pandas.DataFrames` that contain the whole csv-file. So pretty sure not more than 2 Gb of memory should be needed. `getsizeof(dataframe)` also does not return a huge number. Then in a function, I do the following: Finding an interesting value, let it be an outliner of say the motor current. Then plot 10 seconds (about 300 data points) around this point in a graph with `bokeh` and moreover 4 other graphs for motor voltage, motor speed and so on. This function is plotting about 50 graphs all the same way in a for-loop. Variables are defined locally, so they are overwritten each loop. Now the big question: Why is my memory getting fuller each iteration? Sometimes it reaches about 7 Gb and I get a memory error. I don't see how my data is getting that big internally. The memory thing even occurs with csv-files of 10 mb of size.

Answer (score 0):

Python did not free memory even after the end of a function's lifetime. `del variablename` didn't free memory either.

This did the trick:

```
import gc

gc.collect()
```